# How to clean up JSP dependencies in a big project

Tags: java, maven, jsp, ide

I am cleaning up a big java/maven project that has JSP pages for displaying frontend components, and also backend part so serve models and business logic. Some parts of the code is not used anymore and should be removed, including both jsp and backend components. The project has roughly the following structure (only relevant parts shown):

- *src/main/java/** for backend part
- *src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/components/*.jsp* for jsp code.

Example jsp file:

```html
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/taglibs.jsp"%>

<layout:layout-render name="body" layoutType="${model.page.layout}">
    <layout:layout-component name="title">${model.page.title}</layout:layout-component>
    <layout:layout-component name="sidebar">
        <layout:layout-render name="components/component_sidebar" prefix="pages" />
    </layout:layout-component>
</layout:layout-render>
```

I am interested in an automatic way to see the dependency graph/tree of JSPs:

- to other JSPs (line with *name="components/component_sidebar"*)
- to JAVA models (line with *layoutType="${model.page.layout}"*)

Are there any maven or IDE plugins, scripts or anything else to do this job?

Comment: did you find something eventually?

Comment: @remi not really, unfortunately. The usage of jsp code is throughout the java code, and so deleting jsp files one by one was the solution, so far. If the java code isn't used, I just remove the relevant jsp files and dependants, making sure they are not cross-referenced from other places. It is tedious, but is better than keeping the unused files

Comment: thanks. I also didn't find automatic way to see the dependency graph of JSPs, but i used [webgraphviz.com](http://www.webgraphviz.com) to the see the dependency graph i manually created.